# Excessive video buffering on a minimal laptop running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, video, battery, ram, bios

I have a Dell Latitude E7240 on which I installed Ubuntu 18.04. It has 8Gb RAM and a 16Gb mSATA SSD which is 2/3rds full with the OS. My problem is too much video buffering, which may be due to a fixed video memory of 64Mb in an older BIOS A18. I was thinking about upgrading to A27, but the Dell website has only instructions for Windows .exe files, and some webpages here in Ask Ubuntu are obsolete. Can anyone give me current detailed instructions on what to do? I should mention that it has no battery, and operates with only an AC adapter. Thanks.

Comment: Questions about firmware updates unless when supported by the new Debian/Ubuntu tool for that purpose (not applicable to BIOS, only UEFI) are off/topic here. And your assumption that a newer BIOS version will be able to assign more RAM to video is baseless. And it has nothing to do with the "problem" in the title.

Comment: For some reason, some manufacturers have decided to make software to update the firmware while the operating system is running, despite it being risky to do so-- a failed firmware update often results in bricked hardware. BIOS/firmware updates are best done through the firmware itself. You should consult the documentation for your motherboard. Every board is different. You cannot update your motherboard firmware using Ubuntu unless your manufacturer has written a utility for Linux for this purpose.  But as mentioned, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

These system firmware updates can simply be transferred to a FAT-formatted USB drive and can be performed from the firmware according to [Dell's own instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-hr/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=cvj6j&oscode=w864&productcode=latitude-e7240-ultrabook) (see the section called "Installation Instructions") provided with the firmware. There is a "BIOS Update" option available within the one-time boot device selection menu, found by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> during POST. You can then select the file from the drive using the arrow keys.

I don't know if this will help resolve your buffering issues, however.

Comment: I did this already, but it didn’t work. The BIOS update requires a battery, which is why I mentioned it was absent..

Comment: Also, I heard from a Dell forum that integrated video memory cannot be increased, so I guess I’m stuck. Thx anyway.

Comment: The executable mentioned it can be run from MS-DOS, have you tried running it from FreeDOS?

Comment: Thanks, but due to the Dell comment above, and my unfamiliarity with FreeDOS, I didn't want to brick my PC, so I'm trying some other steps.

Comment: If you believe there is an issue with the BIOS, surely it must be worth installing Windows or buying a battery just to do the BIOS update?

Comment: The Dell forum said upgrading the BIOS would not allow me to increase an integrated video memory, and my computer has only a 16GB mSATA SSD, which is obsolete. Thanks anyway.